# SAM build - does it also build layers?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm new to both lambda's and also SAM - so if I've screwed anything simple up don't yell :D.

**Summary:** I can't get `sam build` to build a layer specified in `template.yaml`, it only builds the lambda function.

**Background**: I'm trying to build a lambda function in python3.7 that uses the skimage (`scikit-image`) module.  To do that, I'm trying to use SAM to build and deploy it all.  *...this is working*

I'm trying to deploy the scikit-image module as a layer (and also build with SAM), rather than having it included in the lambda function direction  *...this isn't working*

---

As a start, I'm simply extending the standard SAM `Hello World` app.

I've got skimage working by simply add it to `requirements.txt` , then using `sam build -u`, then manually removing the numpy/scipy dependencies from the built package directory (I've got the AWS scipy/numpy layer included).

(I added import numpy, scipy.ndimage and skimage.draw to the standard hello world app, and included some test function calls to each)

requirements.txt:

```
requests
scikit-image
```

After that, everything works fine (running locally and/or on AWS).

---

However, I'd now like to move the skimage module out of my app and into a new custom layer (I'd like to have skimage in a layer to re-use for a few functions)

To set that up, I've created a dependencies directory and moved requirements.txt into there (leaving empty requirements.txt in the app directory).
I then updated template.yaml to also specify the new layer:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Layers:
              - arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:420165488524:layer:AWSLambda-Python37-SciPy1x:2
              - !Ref SkimageLayer
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

  SkimageLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: Skimage
      Description: Skimage module layer
      ContentUri: dependencies/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
              - python3.7
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
    DependsOn:
            - Skimage
```

directory structure:

```
▾ dependencies/                
    requirements.txt (responses and scikit-image)          
▸ events/                      
▾ hello_world/                 
    __init__.py                
    app.py                     
    requirements.txt (now empty)          
▸ tests/                       
  README.md                    
  template.yaml
```

However, when I run `sam build -u` with that template file, nothing gets built for the layer specified in `./dependencies`: `SkimageLayer` in the template.yml file.  However the `HelloWorldFunction` still gets built correctly (now of course without any included modules)

Comment: I'm working a bit based on this: https://noise.getoto.net/2019/02/06/working-with-aws-lambda-and-lambda-layers-in-aws-sam/.
About halfway down he implies with how he does it that SAM build wont build a layer itself, as he manually runs npm install inside his node dependencies directory to install the node dependencies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [SAM Cli version v0.50.0](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/releases/tag/v0.50.0), it is building layers as part of `sam build`.

[Design document](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/blob/develop/designs/build_for_layers.md) could be a good starting point to understand how it works.

Basically you have to set a custom `BuildMethod` with your lambda's target runtime:

```
MyLayer:
Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
Properties:
  ContentUri: my_layer
  CompatibleRuntimes:
    - python3.8
Metadata:
  BuildMethod: python3.8 (or nodejs8.10 etc..)
```

**Warning**: For compiled language as Java, it [has a issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/2033) which it tries to build layers before functions. It's expected to have it fixed on the next release ([PR opened already](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/pull/2042)).

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer - **No**, currently SAM does **not** *build* layers you define in a SAM `template.yaml` file.

*It will **only** build any **functions** you define*.

However (curiously) it **will** package (upload to S3) and deploy (setup within AWS, assign ARN so it can be used etc) any layers you define.

---

There is a feature request on the SAM github issues to implement layer building with SAM.

---

T**his can actually be hacked right now to get SAM to build your layers as well**, by creating a dummy function in your SAM template file, as well as a layer entry, and having the layer ContentUri entry point to the .aws-sam build directory that gets created for the function.

[See my post here on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58408130/9423009)

That approach actually seems to work pretty well for twisting SAM right now to build your layers for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if something changed recently but I'm able to do this without issue. My template file and structure is very similar to the OP except I've put all my common code into...

`/dependencies/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`

I didn't include a requirements.txt file in that directory... just the `__init__.py` file and various `.py` files that I need to import into my functions.

SAM then finds the code and builds the layer. You don't even need to zip the contents of the directory as some tutorials tell you to do.

The best part is `Layers:` is able to be put into the `Globals:` section of the template file so that the layer is available to all of your functions!

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Handler: main.lambda_handler
    Timeout: 10
    Runtime: python3.7
    Layers: 
        - !Ref HelperFunctions

Resources:
  HelperFunctions:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: MyHelperFunctions
      Description: My Lambda Layer with Helper Functions for accessing RDS, Logging, and other utilities.
      ContentUri: dependencies/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.6
        - python3.7
      LicenseInfo: MIT
      RetentionPolicy: Delete
```

Comment: Appreciate this answer -- I'll give this approach a try.

Comment: Problem with this right now is you build all the dependencies on your local. Some might not work after deploy. `numpy` for example would have this issue.

Comment: The path is important. The directory name of 'dependencies' is just one I chose but everything beneath it is important and must follow this configuration. If you do, the site packages should be found when uploading the layer. I haven't tried doing it with numpy but I fail to understand how it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Karuhanga - when you use SAM, there is the option with sam build (I think it's -u flag?) to build inside an AWS lambda environment docker container.  That way it builds locally, but uses the correct AWS environment.  Therefore everything builds 'natively' for lambda.  I use this without problems for numpy etc.

Comment: @Karuhanga - also NOTE - AWS supplies a pre-built numpy/scipy layer for you to use - you don't need to build your own layer for numpy/scipy if that's all you need a layer for.

Comment: @Richard how would you reference code built in a docker container in the contentUri?

Comment: In code, it's simply a bunch of packaged modules, so usual import statements.
In SAM build, like this:
AQSTestCTACR:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: aqs_test_ct_acr
      Runtime: python3.7
      CodeUri: ./src/
      Handler: ct_acr.lambda_handler
      MemorySize: 2048
      Timeout: 15
      Role: arn:aws:iam::XXXX
      Layers:
              - arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:XXXX:layer:AWSLambda-Python37-SciPy1x:2
              - arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:XXXX:layer:AQSTestModules:3

Comment: The above isn't formatted :(.  But I build a lambda with reference to two layers - the one I built, and then also the 'included' AWS numpy/scipy layer

Comment: Thank you. Tried it. `sam` mounts your folder to the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS team must have made things easier, relative to these older answers. From the current docs, all you do is list a layer as a property in your template (Nov 2020):

```
ServerlessFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: .
    Handler: my_handler
    Runtime: Python3.7
    Layers:
        - arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:111111111111:layer:myLayer:1
        - arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:111111111111:layer:mySecondLayer:1
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-layers.html

Comment: The OP question is about building layers using SAM template and not re-using layer inside SAM template

Comment: Great point @VadimK. Hopefully someone will still find use from my comment as it is related and there is not much out there.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following script. Tested with Ubuntu 18 and CodeBuild

It pip install's the layer's requirements to `.aws-sam/build/layername/python/`. Then you can run `sam package` and `sam deploy` as normal

`build-layers.py`:

```
import yaml
import subprocess
import sys
import shutil

SAM_BUILD_PATH = ".aws-sam/build"

with open("template.yaml", "r") as f:
    template = yaml.safe_load(f)

for key, resource in template["Resources"].items():
    if resource["Type"] not in ["AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion", "AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion"]:
        continue
    properties = resource["Properties"]
    content_uri = properties["ContentUri"]
    layer_name = properties["LayerName"]
    requirements_path = f"{content_uri}/requirements.txt"

    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "-r", requirements_path, "-t", f"{SAM_BUILD_PATH}/{layer_name}/python"])

shutil.copyfile("template.yaml", f"{SAM_BUILD_PATH}/template.yaml")
```

`template.yaml`:

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  pandas:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: pandas
      ContentUri: pandas
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.6
        - python3.7
        - python3.8
  sqlparse:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: sqlparse
      ContentUri: sqlparse
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.6
        - python3.7
        - python3.8
```

so call `python build-layers.py` first, then `sam package` then `sam deploy`

my directories look like this:

```
lambda
  layers
    pandas
      requirements.txt (content = pandas)
    sqlparse
      requirements.txt (content = sqlparse)
  template.yaml
  build-layers.py
```

`buildspec.yml`:

```
---  # build spec for AWS CodeBuild

version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.8
    commands:
      - pip install aws-sam-cli
  build:
    commands:
      - cd lambda/layers
      - python build-layers.py
      - sam package --s3-bucket foo --s3-prefix sam/lambda/layers | sam deploy --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM -t /dev/stdin --stack-name LAYERS
```

Comment: Hey Neil - I'll have to check that.  ...you got it to work _without_ specifying a function?  The only way previously to 'fool' SAM into building a layer for you was to associate it with a dummy function.  You couldn't specify only a layer in the template yaml file.  But you seem to be able to do that!  That would be good if they've changed that now

Comment: Sweet - I'll have to check it out then